# How to work around a matrix dimension error with funtion intersect?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, intersect

I have a 1000x1000 matrix A (containing values ​​from 0 to 150) and a 181x1 vector B. In my matrix A, I want to keep only those values ​​that are present in B while keeping A with the same size.
I tried with the function ismember but it doesn't give me the result that I expect. So I tried an other function
Here is what I do as code

```
A=A.*intersect(A,B,'stable');
```

But I have this error

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How can I do solve the problem?

Comment: What should the value of elements in A not in B become? Is zero ok?

Comment: Yes for now I leave on the fact that they become zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is [**`ismember`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for this task as follows:

```
A = A.*ismember(A,B);
% ismember(A,B) gives the logical matrix containing 1's for the indexes whose values 
% are present in `B` and 0's for all other indexes. When this logical matrix is 
% element-wise multiplied with A, all the indexes of A whose elements are not in B 
% become zero
```

---

**Why does your code not work?**

That's because with [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)`(A, B, 'stable')`, you get a column vector containing (most probably) less than or (very less probably) equal to the number of elements of `A`. Even if equal, you will get the same error when you multiply it element-wise with `A` since `A` is not a column vector. Element-wise multiplication requires the order of both matrices to be same because only that's when each element of a matrix can be multiplied with the corresponding element in the other matrix.

The code that I showed above with [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) takes care of this as already explained in the comments.

Comment: Accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Create two matrices, `A` and `B`, with random numbers. `C` is an array with values that are both in `A` and `B`, using `ismember` we can select which values in `A` to keep.

```
A = randi([0 150], 1000, 1000);
B = randi([0 150], 181, 1);
C = intersect(A, B, 'stable');
A(~ismember(A, C)) = 0;
```